# Rails is allowing double post request to lock database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, post, file-upload, concurrency

I'm using [Valums Ajax Uploader](http://valums.com/ajax-upload/) to create a nice user interface for uploading photos in my rails app. One problem, it sometimes submits Post requests too close together, and then they cause a database locking exception which makes all the uploads fail for a while.

Here's an example of the log:

```
Started POST "/photos?authenticity_token=WPJo8nnJ3KSoG9O%2B%2Flz%2BPbvdtX8cmbEaVB8TidnLx5Y%3D&qqfile=IMG_0417.JPG" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-03-06 22:39:25 -0600
Processing by PhotosController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"file"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f9e5529f518 @original_filename="IMG_0417.JPG", @content_type="application/octet-stream", @headers=nil, @tempfile=#<File:/var/folders/mf/06zfbjcn63j6p2rqvt6tc77c0000gn/T/raw-upload.20120306-53350-13pew0o>>, "authenticity_token"=>"WPJo8nnJ3KSoG9O+/lz+PbvdtX8cmbEaVB8TidnLx5Y=", "qqfile"=>"IMG_0417.JPG"}
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1


Started POST "/photos?authenticity_token=WPJo8nnJ3KSoG9O%2B%2Flz%2BPbvdtX8cmbEaVB8TidnLx5Y%3D&qqfile=IMG_0418.JPG" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-03-06 22:39:30 -0600
Processing by PhotosController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"file"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fcfddd8d268 @original_filename="IMG_0418.JPG", @content_type="application/octet-stream", @headers=nil, @tempfile=#<File:/var/folders/mf/06zfbjcn63j6p2rqvt6tc77c0000gn/T/raw-upload.20120306-53383-1plhm8r>>, "authenticity_token"=>"WPJo8nnJ3KSoG9O+/lz+PbvdtX8cmbEaVB8TidnLx5Y=", "qqfile"=>"IMG_0418.JPG"}
 "authenticity_token"=>"WPJo8nnJ3KSoG9O+/lz+PbvdtX8cmbEaVB8TidnLx5Y=", "qqfile"=>"IMG_0418.JPG"}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
  SQL (0.6ms)  INSERT INTO "photos" ("city", "comments_updated_at", "context_id", "country", "created_at", "custom_title", "description", "featured", "flagged", "focus_id", "full_downloads", "height", "image", "lat", "lng", "place", "presentation_downloads", "state", "status", "updated_at", "user_id", "width") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["city", nil], ["comments_updated_at", nil], ["context_id", nil], ["country", nil], ["created_at", Tue, 06 Mar 2012 22:39:37 CST -06:00], ["custom_title", nil], ["description", nil], ["featured", false], ["flagged", nil], ["focus_id", nil], ["full_downloads", 0], ["height", 2304], ["image", "admin_tester_630cm1715.JPG"], ["lat", nil], ["lng", nil], ["place", nil], ["presentation_downloads", 0], ["state", nil], ["status", "batch"], ["updated_at", Tue, 06 Mar 2012 22:39:37 CST -06:00], ["user_id", 1], ["width", 3072]]
  SQL (0.2ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "photos_count" = COALESCE("photos_count", 0) + 1 WHERE "users"."id" = 1
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1
  SQL (5064.0ms)  INSERT INTO "photos" ("city", "comments_updated_at", "context_id", "country", "created_at", "custom_title", "description", "featured", "flagged", "focus_id", "full_downloads", "height", "image", "lat", "lng", "place", "presentation_downloads", "state", "status", "updated_at", "user_id", "width") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  [["city", nil], ["comments_updated_at", nil], ["context_id", nil], ["country", nil], ["created_at", Tue, 06 Mar 2012 22:39:43 CST -06:00], ["custom_title", nil], ["description", nil], ["featured", false], ["flagged", nil], ["focus_id", nil], ["full_downloads", 0], ["height", 2304], ["image", "admin_tester_630cm171b.JPG"], ["lat", nil], ["lng", nil], ["place", nil], ["presentation_downloads", 0], ["state", nil], ["status", "batch"], ["updated_at", Tue, 06 Mar 2012 22:39:43 CST -06:00], ["user_id", 1], ["width", 3072]]
SQLite3::BusyException: database is locked: INSERT INTO "photos" ("city", "comments_updated_at", "context_id", "country", "created_at", "custom_title", "description", "featured", "flagged", "focus_id", "full_downloads", "height", "image", "lat", "lng", "place", "presentation_downloads", "state", "status", "updated_at", "user_id", "width") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
   (0.3ms)  rollback transaction
SQLite3::BusyException: cannot rollback transaction - SQL statements in progress: rollback transaction
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 17749ms

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (SQLite3::BusyException: cannot rollback transaction - SQL statements in progress: rollback transaction):
  app/controllers/photos_controller.rb:29:in `create'
  app/uploaders/flash_session_cookie_middleware.rb:16:in `call'
```

Obviously this isn't good, if this happens with just one user uploading a few images it isn't up to production standards. So, how do you fix this? What is the right way to handle uploading and processing a file like this so that concurrency isn't a big problem?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to migrate from SQLite if you're having multiple processes accessing the same database. While this is supported by SQLite, it does require a lock on the entire database to avoid corrupting data during commits. This is explained in rough terms in the [SQLite FAQ](http://sqlite.org/faq.html#q5).

While SQLite is great for small-scale databases and development work, it is probably not the best idea for a production grade application that sees a lot of write activity.

The good news is that converting from SQLite to MySQL or Postgres is usually very simple.

You could be hitting some kind of deadlock condition due to the way SQLite handles locking. It's also odd that your uploads would be taking such an extended period of time to process.